# SQL CASE statement with IF condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following `CASE` statement. It calculates a date based on the `CASE` statement. How do I get it to skip records if it is about to give a record a date that is lower than the date it gave the previous record?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        -- If there is a already a date, use it
        WHEN LENGTH(DT) = 8 THEN DT::DATE
        WHEN '2019Q1' >= '2018Q1'
        --There are some additional conditions that are in this THEN
        --statement. For simplicity sake, I have removed them. 
        THEN THRU_DT::DATE - 30 
        ELSE THRU_DT::DATE
    END AS DT
FROM table;
```

**Input:**

| patient_num | dt | claim_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 232 |  | 2423 |
| 232 |  | 3323 |

**Output:**

| patient_num | dt | claim_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 232 | 2018-08-01 | 2423 |
| 232 | 2018-07-01 | 3323 |

**Expected output:**

| patient_num | dt | claim_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 232 | 2018-08-01 | 2423 |
| 232 |  | 3323 |

I do not want the second record to be given a date because that date is less than the date that was given to the first record.

Note that a particular patient can have several records. I am only using two records above to show an example of what I am expecting.

Comment: How do you define "previous record"?

Comment: There's no intrinsic "previous record" as in SQL the data sets are implicitly un-ordered sets.  If your set contains data where you can *calculate* an order, then you can use that calculation *(such as `ORDER BY claim_no`)*.